# Can you use something like an image to ip log someone without them clicking on a link? (read below what happened below)

Tags: security, ip, discord

Ok recently, my friend was talking about drama he got involved in with discord and Idk the whole story and no names here. He then told me he learned that the people he was arguing with were planning to ip log him and he had a vpn on during that time for the duration. That person who claimed he was going to send him an image that could get his ip without needing to click on it didn't send him anything but claimed he did. Idk if this is possible at all. The person who with the "image" thing had said it could get one's ip without the need to click on it by just sending it, but then asked someone to shorten it for him before trying to get to my friend(who blocked them all after learning of their malicious intents) and saying he made a paragraph to sc but my friend said he received no image from him . However, I think a lot of people have dismissed this idea to both of us and the person who intended to ip log him. So far I've been telling him is from what I heard and saw they were just most likely trying to intimidate him as to what it sounds like and there most likely was no way that they could have gotten his ip unless he had clicked on a link or was in a call so he wouldn't need to worry about anything and should move on before anything worse happens since I told him I almost fell for something similar.

Point of my question is wondering if it's possible to get someone's ip on somewhere like discord other than using grabify or iplogger even if you're not interacting with the person or either that person doesn't click/download the data you send them to log their ip such as using an image? The only other thing I heard was something like wireshark but from what I heard it would be difficult. Evidence or an explanation would be appreciated as I'm uncertain what to tell him rn.

Comment: You can't see an image unless your device already has it downloaded to it's web-cache.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), ***read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)***, and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

The webserver that hosts the image will always see the external IP of any device requesting the file to display the data. To get the IP you ned to tweak the server a bit.

It is very possible. With a custom image-hosting setup you will get the IP of the device if it is on mobile networks or directly connected to the internet and not behind a router.

If the device is using ethernet or wifi somewhere, the server will probably just see the IP of the router or residential gateway though.